# Removing "index.php?access=" from the url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to hide a part of the url, I check the other similar answers about that, but nothing works...

My actual url can be like that :
"https://philippebeck.net/index.php?access=photo"

With a simple access who's the controller name

Or it can be like that too :
"https://philippebeck.net/index.php?id=42&access=photo!read"

With an id in first & a compound access (controller!method)

But I would like to have those results :

Without id :
"https://philippebeck.net/photo"

And if an Htaccess Master read this message, with id :
"https://philippebeck.net/photo!read/42

Or, if an Htaccess Champion read this message, with id & method separate from the controller :
"https://philippebeck.net/photo/read/42

The best I could do alone give me this poor result :
"https://philippebeck.net/?access=photo"

And did not work on my portfolio page, only this one, why !? Don't know...

Heartbreaking !

For the moment, my .htaccess allow me to force https & to force without www :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in .htaccess file**

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```